# realizar una division y mostrar todos los decimales en un String o en Un StringBuffer

Tags: java

Estoy realizando un programa que me realice una división y me muestre todos los decimales del cociente ya lo hice por bigDecimal pero no me muestra todos los decimales que quiero y estoy tratando de todas las maneras pero no he podido como podria realizarla y que me muestre n decimales sin importar el tiempo de ejecucion los numero de ´pruebas son 2/149  y 1/14911941  , 1/141140  que tienen mas de 7 mil decimales o 33 mil decimales

Comment: ¿Puedes copiar el código que estás usando?

Answer (score 1):

Cuando divides dos números enteros el resultado tiene un número infinito de decimales si y solo si el denominador de la fracción simplificada es múltiplo de algún número primo distinto de 2 y 5.

Pero todas las divisiones de números enteros con infinitos decimales tienen algo en común, llega un momento en que se repiten. Y es posible representar todos los infinitos decimales poniendo la parte inicial que no se repite seguida de la que sí se repite.

Por ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Que significa que el grupo de 6 cifras bajo el arco se repite infinitamente.

Esto se calcula almacenando los dividendos a partir de la coma decimal, y cuando se repiten has encontrado el ciclo. También almacenamos los cocientes, que serán el resultado.

```
1.-  6 entre 7 es 0 y sobran 6, multiplico el resto por 10 para el siguiente decimal
2.- 60 entre 7 es 8 y sobran 4, multiplico el resto por 10 para el siguiente decimal
3.- 40 entre 7 es 5 y sobran 5, multiplico el resto por 10 para el siguiente decimal
4.- 50 entre 7 es 7 y sobra  1, multiplico el resto por 10 para el siguiente decimal
5.- 10 entre 7 es 1 y sobran 3, multiplico el resto por 10 para el siguiente decimal
6.- 30 entre 7 es 4 y sobran 2, multiplico el resto por 10 para el siguiente decimal
7.- 20 entre 7 es 2 y sobran 6, multiplico el resto por 10 para el siguiente decimal
8.- 60 entre 7 .....
```

¡60! está repetido. Hemos encontrado nuestro ciclo. Este es desde los pasos 2 (inclusive) al 8 (no inclusive)

Y ahora lo mismo en java.

```
import java.util.*;
public class DecimalesInfinitos {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        division(6,7);
        division(73,30);
        division(2,149);
        division(1,14911941);
        division(1,141140);
    }

    public static void division(long dividendo, long divisor) {
        assert( dividendo>=0 && divisor>0 );
        System.out.println( "" + dividendo + "/" + divisor + "=" );
        // Primero la parte entera
        long cocienteEntero = dividendo/divisor;
        // Ahora la parte decimal
        dividendo %= divisor;
        List<Long> listaDividendos = new ArrayList<>();
        List<Long> listaCocientes  = new ArrayList<>();
        dividendo *= 10;
        while(!listaDividendos.contains( dividendo )) {
            if ( dividendo==0 ) {
                imprimeNumeroSinInfinitosDecimales( 
                    cocienteEntero, listaCocientes);
                return;
            }
            listaDividendos.add( dividendo );
            listaCocientes .add( dividendo / divisor );
            dividendo %= divisor;
            dividendo *= 10;
        }
        // Localizar donde empieza la parte periódica
        long indiceInicioPeriodo = listaDividendos.indexOf(dividendo);
        // Imprimimos la parte entera y el separador decimal
        System.out.print( cocienteEntero );
        System.out.print( "'");
        // Imprimir la parte no periódica
        int i = 0;
        for (; i<indiceInicioPeriodo; ++i)
            System.out.print( listaCocientes.get(i).longValue() );
        // Imprimir un subrayado para indicar el inicio de la parte periódica
        System.out.print("_");
        // Imprimir la parte periódica
        for (; i<listaCocientes.size(); ++i )
            System.out.print( listaCocientes.get(i).longValue() );
        // Y unos puntitos para indicar que se repiten
        System.out.println("...");
    }

    public static void imprimeNumeroSinInfinitosDecimales( 
                    long cocienteEntero, List<Long> listaCocientes) {
        System.out.print( cocienteEntero );
        System.out.print( "'");
        for ( long n : listaCocientes )
            System.out.print(n);
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

Que nos da como resultado :

> 6/7=
>   0'_857142...
>   73/30=
>   2'4_3...
>   2/149=
>   0'_0134228187919463087248322147651006711409395973154362416107382550335570469798657718120805369127516778523489932885906040268456375838926174496644295302...
>   1/14911941=
>   1/141140=   (omito estos dos resultado porque SO permite solo 30000 caracteres)

Los resultados los muestro diréctamente en pantalla en vez de en un StringBuffer o String. Adaptarlo a que los almacene en un StringBuffer o String queda como ejercicio para el lector.

Answer (score 0):

para cuando realices una pregunta, por favor proporciona el avance de tu código o el error que te arroja, para mostrar decimales tienes diferentes  caminos, te muestro un ejemplo con BigDecimal:

```
          BigDecimal bg1, bg2, bg3;

          bg1 = new BigDecimal("1");
          bg2 = new BigDecimal("141140");

          bg3 = bg1.divide(bg2, 3500, RoundingMode.CEILING);

          String str = "El resultado es: " +bg3;

          System.out.println( str );
```

Tambien puedes apoyarte con [setScale](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int,%20int))

Usando    [DecimalFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html)

```
         double number= 1.42423423423423;
          DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
          System.out.println(df.format(number));
          /* Salida : 1.42*/
```

Comment: OP dijo que BigDecimal no le alcanzaba. En realidad nada le alcanza para lo que quiere

Answer (score 0):

lo que pides no se puede realizar debido a que cada tipo de variable almacena cierta cantidad de bytes, si deseas obtener por ejemplos todos los decimales de PI, solo te arrojaría unos cuantos.

Comment: esto no es una respuesta (en si), si no mas bien un comentario. podrias ponerlo alli? gracias.

Comment: ¿Cual es tu definición de respuesta? El decir que no se puede es una respuesta, o solo son respuesta cuando soluciono el problema (osea pongo código)?

Comment: Completamente de acuerdo Nyro22. Que una respuesta sea breve no significa que sea un comentario. Yo mejoraría tu respuesta aclarando que te refieres a números irracionales. Para los racionales sí se puede representar todos los dígitos con notación periódica, aunque también es cierto que no se pueden representar todos literalmente ni siquiera en el caso de los racionales. Tendrás mi +1 entonces.